# What RPC can I use to query the balance of an arbitrary address

Tags: json-rpc

How do I get the balance of an arbitrary address using Bitcoin RPC calls? From the RPC calls I can see you are required to have the private key or an `account` to use the RPC.

For illustrations sake, if you could demo querying this address:

`1HB5XMLmzFVj8ALj6mfBsbifRoD4miY36v`

That would be great. [Here](https://blockchain.info/address/1HB5XMLmzFVj8ALj6mfBsbifRoD4miY36v) is the actual balance for this address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been answered here:

- [Calculating address balance](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10895/calculating-address-balance)
- [How to get an address's balance with the bitcoin client?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10090/how-to-get-an-addresss-balance-with-the-bitcoin-client)

The pull request for this feature (support for watch-only addresses) can be found at: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/4045

Comment: When a question has previously been answered, it is usually best to flag it as a duplicate, rather than posting a new answer.  If you have information to add (like the pull request), please add it as an answer or comment to the previous question.

Comment: @NateEldredge I obviously couldn't add a new answer to the previous question just to add the pull request info. I could post it as a comment but then again do you see a place it could fit? I don't. On top of that, a question should be marked as duplicate if not only the question context is identical to a previous question but their answers are also identical, at least according to our mod David Schwartz: http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/45/closed-as-exact-duplicate-due-to-significant-overlap#comment69_53